# Flickering with infinite CSS3 Animation

Tags: css

I'm seeing some strange intermittent flickering in this CSS3 animation. This is currently appearing for us in Chrome.

https://codepen.io/jwhitewd/pen/oQxZxy

HTML

```
 <div class="sk-cube-grid">
      <div class="sk-cube sk-cube1"></div>
      <div class="sk-cube sk-cube2"></div>
      <div class="sk-cube sk-cube3"></div>
      <div class="sk-cube sk-cube4"></div>
      <div class="sk-cube sk-cube5"></div>
      <div class="sk-cube sk-cube6"></div>
      <div class="sk-cube sk-cube7"></div>
      <div class="sk-cube sk-cube8"></div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
 .sk-cube-grid .sk-cube {
      width: 33%;
      height: 33%;
      background-color: #7B7B7B;
      border-left:6px solid #ffcc00;
      float: left;
      margin:5px;
      border-radius:2px;
      -webkit-animation: sk-cubeGridScaleDelay 2.3s infinite ease-in-out;
              animation: sk-cubeGridScaleDelay 2.3s infinite ease-in-out; 
    }
    .sk-cube-grid .sk-cube1 {
      -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
              animation-delay: 0.2s; }
    .sk-cube-grid .sk-cube2 {
      -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
              animation-delay: 0.3s; }
    .sk-cube-grid .sk-cube3 {
      -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
              animation-delay: 0.4s; }
    .sk-cube-grid .sk-cube4 {
      -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
              animation-delay: 0.1s; }
    .sk-cube-grid .sk-cube5 {
      -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
              animation-delay: 0.2s; }
    .sk-cube-grid .sk-cube6 {
      -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
              animation-delay: 0.3s; }
    .sk-cube-grid .sk-cube7 {
      -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
              animation-delay: 0s; }
    .sk-cube-grid .sk-cube8 {
      -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
              animation-delay: 0.2s; }

    @-webkit-keyframes sk-cubeGridScaleDelay {
      0%, 70%, 100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale3D(1.2, 1.2, 1.2);
                transform: scale3D(1.2, 1.2, 1.2);
      } 35% {
        -webkit-transform: scale3D(0, 0, 1);
                transform: scale3D(0, 0, 1); 
      }
    }

    @keyframes sk-cubeGridScaleDelay {
      0%, 70%, 100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale3D(1, 1, 1);
                transform: scale3D(1, 1, 1);
      } 35% {
        -webkit-transform: scale3D(0, 0, 1);
                transform: scale3D(0, 0, 1);
      } 
    }
```

What could be causing this? Presumably it has something to do with the timing and scaling of the animation, but we can't figure out what it might be.

Also worth noting, this issue does only appear on Chrome for Windows and not on MacOS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set the height of the cubes in `px` rather than `%`, e.g.:

```
height: 20px;
```

See updated codepen: [flickering](https://codepen.io/creativesingh/pen/ZPjveM)

Comment: So while this did fix one aspect of the flickering, we're still seeing some other flicker on the rectangles as well.

Comment: can you please add screenshot, it is working fine on my end